# What is the performance impact of importing Javascript and CSS stylesheets in Freemarker files?

Tags: javascript, css, amazon-web-services, freemarker, cdn

I am working on a project where we use the Freemarker template engine for the front end. A lot of files in the project have a similar structure, in importing some 3rd party libraries and stylesheets like JQuery, Bootstrap, ect. For the sake of consistency, one of the developers suggested having one file as a standardized template containing a header section and scripts. And we import this file into all other files. As a result, any one file into which this template is being imported into will have a lot of unused scripts and stylesheets.

Are there any criticisms with this approach, as opposed to importing scripts in a case by case basis? Does it effect performance? These scripts are being loaded from some standard CDNs and the app will eventually be hosted on a AWS server.

Comment: This is not FreeMarker related. You can very well do the same in say JSF or JSP. And even then.. it all depends.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no real criticism with this approach, as it makes use of Freemarker's ability to provide reusable and modular UI. However, this is more of good coding practising than performance.
You **should** create reusable UI components whenever you could, and header is one main example.

It's good for code integrity and readability to define a template for header `header.ftl` or `head.ftl` and import it from all your pages, and even do the same for main menu and footer as well.

To ramp up performance with Freemarker consider switching on Freemarker caching from Java, XML, or properties config based on your app type. Combining caching with recuction of code size through re-usability will help page loading time.